# Is the ring of all algebraic integers coherent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Is the ring of all algebraic integers coherent?
Here is the definition of a [coherent ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_ring).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. In fact every finitely generated ideal is principal.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_domain

Comment: Dear Countinghaus, How do you prove that the ring of all algebraic integers is a Bezout domain?

Comment: This is a little gross and there's probably an easier argument, but given a finitely generated ideal there is an ideal of an honest number field generated by the same generators; this ideal becomes principal after a finite extension (e.g. by capitulation of ideals in the Hilbert class field) and the generator of that new ideal is also a generator for your original ideal.